# Prime factor wanted of the huge number $\sum_{j=1}^{10} j!^{j!}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, factorial, prime-factorization

> What is the smallest prime factor of $$\sum_{j=1}^{10} j!^{j!}$$ ?

- Trial :

This number has $23\ 804\ 069$ digits , so if it were prime it would be a record prime. I do not think however that this number is prime. According to my calculations , it has no prime factor below $10^{10}$. To establish its compositeness I search the smallest prime factor.

- Motivation

The fast growing function $$f(n):=\sum_{j=1}^n j!^{j!}$$ cannot be a prime number for any positive integer $n$ except from $n=2$ (which gives a very small prime) and $n=10$ (which might give a prime). The reason is that $13\mid f(n)$ holds for every integer $n\ge 12$ and for the other cases , prime factors can easily be found. This makes this case interesting since it completes the primality search.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

$2198910029959$ is a prime factor (that's about $2 \times 10^{12}$). I'm about $90\%$ sure it's the smallest one - the other $10\%$ is if there's a bug in my code or I accidentally forgot to check some of the smaller primes.

You can find my code [here](https://gist.github.com/goedel-gang/5e61a974d1ed712f5260bde4682edd5d). I'm sure it could have been written to be faster/better or there's a better language to do it in :). I observed that the integers are all about the right size that we can get away with using $64$- and occasionally $128$-bit arithmetic and I just thought it would be fun to write a C program to search for factors. It checks about $1.5 \times 10^{6}$ primes per second on my laptop, and I searched several ranges in parallel overnight.

I checked a number of its calculations against a more naïvely written Python program, as well as the final prime factor it produces, and that all checked out.

Comment: I just verified [using Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28Sum+%28i%21%29%5E%28i%21%29+modulo+2198910029959+for+i%3D1+to+10%29+modulo+2198910029959) that this is indeed a prime factor. Amazing work!

Comment: I will need faster tools in the future. PARI/GP is too slow although I implemented a version avoiding to handle huge numbers. Anyway , thanks. I wonder why you are "only" 90% sure if this was a brute force test. What do you think can have gone wrong ?

Comment: I can confirm the factor as well with my PARI/GP self-made function.

Comment: @Peter $90\%$ is probably a bit of an exaggeration. The main problems would be if I've misunderstood the `primesieve` API in some catastrophic way, or there was accidentally some integer overflow somewhere that caused me to miss a smaller prime, or if I typed the ranges in wrong when I set the different instances of it running overnight. I'm not a C expert so I'm a bit hesitant to declare my result absolutely correct. But I think it's likely that it is. I am at least very very sure that I've showed your number is not prime.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Well, since there definitely is a factor (a direct modulo calculation approved this as well) , the number cannot be prime. I expected that we would need ECM which is however slow for such big numbers , but we were "lucky" that an "only" 13-digit factor appeared.

Comment: Great work! You have found an important prime! And also thanks for sharing your code!